# Reading Client Certificate in Servlet

Tags: java, browser, jboss, certificate

I have a Client Server Communication scenario in JBOSS and browser as client(**JAVA PROGRAM**). Initially when the connection is made, Client sends its Certificate to Server. Server extracts the public key of client from certificate and thus communication will continue.
Now my question is
**How to send certificate(.cer) from Client to Server?**
**How to receive the certificate and extract its public key in Server?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**How to send certificate(.cer) from Client to Server?**

Client certificate (.cer, .crt, .pem) and it's corresponding private key (.key) should be packaged into PKCS#12 (.p12, .pfx) or JKS (.jks) container first (keystore). You also should have server's CA certicate packaged as JKS (truststore).

Example using [HttpClient 3.x](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
// truststore
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS", "SUN");
trustStore.load(TestSupertype.class.getResourceAsStream("/client-truststore.jks"), "amber%".toCharArray());
String alg = KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory fac = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(alg);
fac.init(trustStore);
// keystore
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "SunJSSE");
keystore.load(X509Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/etomcat_client.p12"), "etomcat".toCharArray());
String keyAlg = KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
KeyManagerFactory keyFac = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(keyAlg);
keyFac.init(keystore, "etomcat".toCharArray());
// context
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS", "SunJSSE");
ctx.init(keyFac.getKeyManagers(), fac.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
SslContextedSecureProtocolSocketFactory secureProtocolSocketFactory = new SslContextedSecureProtocolSocketFactory(ctx);
Protocol.registerProtocol("https", new Protocol("https", (ProtocolSocketFactory) secureProtocolSocketFactory, 8443));
// test get
HttpMethod get = new GetMethod("https://127.0.0.1:8443/etomcat_x509");
client.executeMethod(get);
// get response body and do what you need with it
byte[] responseBody = get.getResponseBody();
```

You may find working example in [this project](https://github.com/alx3apps/spring-embedded-tomcat/tree/master/etomcat6-test) see `X509Test` class.

With [HttpClient 4.x](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) configuration and syntax would be slightly different:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
// truststore
KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS", "SUN");
ts.load(PostService.class.getResourceAsStream("/truststore.jks"), "amber%".toCharArray());
// if you remove me, you've got 'javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated' on missing truststore
if(0 == ts.size()) throw new IOException("Error loading truststore");
// tmf
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(ts);
// keystore
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "SunJSSE");
ks.load(PostService.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + certName), certPwd.toCharArray());
// if you remove me, you've got 'javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated' on missing keystore
if(0 == ks.size()) throw new IOException("Error loading keystore");
// kmf
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(ks, certPwd.toCharArray());
// SSL
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
// socket
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(ctx, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
Scheme sch = new Scheme("https", 8443, socketFactory);
httpclient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(sch);
// request
HttpMethod get = new GetMethod("https://localhost:8443/foo");
client.executeMethod(get);
IOUtils.copy(get.getResponseBodyAsStream(), System.out);
```

**How to receive the certificate and extract its public key in Server?**

You server must be configurated to require X.509 client certificate authentication. Then during SSL handshake servlet container will recieve certificate, check it against trustore and provide it to application as a request attribute.
In usual case with single certificate you could use this method in servlet environment to extract certificate:

```
protected X509Certificate extractCertificate(HttpServletRequest req) {
    X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
    if (null != certs && certs.length > 0) {
        return certs[0];
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("No X.509 client certificate found in request");
}
```

Comment: I'm coming from a .Net perspective and looking for the Java equivalent of the ASP.Net `Page.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate` is the `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` attribute in `HttpServletRequest` equivalent to that? -- if anyone knows...?