# How to do client certificate based authentication in SparkJava without reverse proxy or Tomcat

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, embedded-jetty, spark-java

I am aware of how to secure a connection: http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#secure

But this does not enable client certificate-based authentication (I am trying to implement Estonian identity card user authentication)

After research I found a link where it is said that it cannot be done in Spark: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sparkjava/dnCKl-W018A

Fortunately it is an old post.

How do to this with SparkJava embedded Jetty container?

Comment: Do you generate keys by yourself or get from Certificate Authorities?

Comment: I am currently generating keys by myself, but in the future I will be getting them from CA.

Comment: So you can't connect to your app over https? Once I used this utility to generate keys http://www.keystore-explorer.org/. And it works for me.

Comment: I can connect over HTTPS, but I cannot read client certificate. 
I need to do the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901248/reading-client-certificate-in-servlet
Unfortunately I don't know how to do this in Spark.

Comment: Don't suppose you found a solution?

Comment: No, I did not find a solution.

Comment: It seems to be possible now as of version 2.6.0 of Spark. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45083389/7131155

Comment: Thank you! Actually I changed the framework to Spring Boot, which enables to do exactly what I needed.