# Mutual authentication with Spark Java

Tags: java, spark-java

I am trying to achieve a mutually authenticated REST API server using spark-java and from the [documentation](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#secure) I see:

secure(keystoreFilePath, keystorePassword, truststoreFilePath, truststorePassword);

... which looks like exactly what I need. However I am only able to do one way authentication of the server, the client certificate never seems to be verified against the truststore. I'm using version 2.1, any advise or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's only a guess, but have you tried upgrading SparkJava to [the current version](http://sparkjava.com/download.html)?

Comment: I'll give that a go, although I did check the release notes and there is no mention of it. Can't hurt to try though.

Comment: ... tried on 2.5.4, didn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Spark in version 2.6.0 has added what you need. Now, there is a second version of `secure`:

```
 /**
     (...)
     * @param needsClientCert    Whether to require client certificate to be supplied in
     *                           request
     (...)
     */
public synchronized Service secure(String keystoreFile,
                                       String keystorePassword,
                                       String truststoreFile,
                                       String truststorePassword,
                                       boolean needsClientCert)
```

It sets `setNeedClientAuth(true)` and `setWantClientAuth(true)` on the underlying Jetty webserver SslContextFactory object.